# Surface area of $D＝\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid 0\leq z\leq 1,x^2＋y^2\leq z^6\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, area

Let solid shape $D$ be
$$D＝\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid 0\leq z\leq 1,\ x^2＋y^2\leq z^6\}\ .
$$
I want to calculate surface area of $D$.

I used polar coordinate, but $\int_0^1 \sqrt {r^2＋\frac 19r^{2/3}}\,dr$ appeared, and I couldn't calculate this integral.

Could you help me ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MathLover Since $z\in[0,1]$, we get $y\in [-1,1]$ because of $y^2\leq x^2+y^2\leq z^6$

Comment: @Jochen It had bound on $x$ and not $z$. Seems OP edited later.

Comment: @Math Lover thank you for your comment. I modified question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is a surface area of revolution. You are rotating the curve $x=z^3$ (or $y=z^3$) about the $z$-axis.

Some more detail: The formula is

$$
A_z=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{1+\Big(\frac{dx}{dz}\Big)^2}\ dz\ .
$$

If you plug everything in, you get a nice integral:

$$
A_z=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}z^3\sqrt{1+9z^4}\ dz=\frac{\pi}{27}(10^{3/2}-1)\ .
$$

Comment: i looked for the formula in wikipedia, it say: $${\displaystyle A=2\pi \int _{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}y{\sqrt {1+\left({\frac {{\text{d}}y}{{\text{d}}x}}\right)^{2}}}\,{\text{d}}x,\ {\mbox{para}}\qquad x_{1}=x(t=a),{\mbox{y }}x_{2}=x(t=b)}$$. so, maybe you should change the first $z$ by $f(z)$ or $z^3$

Comment: I got the same formula from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html
the variable out the 'sqrt' is always different from the integrating variable, exactly $f(t) \sqrt{(something)} dt$. it say for y-axis is (x=f(y)).

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa Yes, you're right. I've edited my answer.